# Why is the value of "net.peerCount" keep changing, though, I've ONLY 2 nodes in my Local Private Ethereum Network?

Tags: peers, ethernodes

I'm currently setting up Local Private Ethereum Network using Puppeth. And followed the steps provided in tutorial: [Provisioning a Local Private Ethereum Network with Puppeth](https://modalduality.org/posts/puppeth/) .

As per the above documentation:

```
7. Connect the two nodes.

console2> admin.nodeInfo.enode {ENODE-URL} 
console1> admin.addPeer({ENODE-URL})

If everything went well, net.peerCount should be 1 in both consoles.
```

But, below is what I'm getting:

**Console 1:**

```
myMac:console1 admin$ geth attach ipc:../node1/geth.ipc
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.7.3-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.9.2
coinbase: 0xf8b09187db667abb9cb1494237e65b3e2c3373a0
at block: 0 (Wed, 10 Jan 2018 21:36:58 +04)
 datadir: /Users/admin/EtherNet/testnet/node1
 modules: admin:1.0 clique:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> admin.addPeer("enode://f48fcf69ba27442ff3813912ec12ea1ad249f14739dabfcadb3985c3654540e047700030adba5800bf33d0adbdd9ca5f1c47aae2498a0d9dafb8c2fd730969b4@[::]:3002"
... ^C
> admin.addPeer("enode://f48fcf69ba27442ff3813912ec12ea1ad249f14739dabfcadb3985c3654540e047700030adba5800bf33d0adbdd9ca5f1c47aae2498a0d9dafb8c2fd730969b4@[::]:3002")
true
> net.peerCount
3
> 
> admin.addPeer("enode://f48fcf69ba27442ff3813912ec12ea1ad249f14739dabfcadb3985c3654540e047700030adba5800bf33d0adbdd9ca5f1c47aae2498a0d9dafb8c2fd730969b4@[::]:3002")
true
> net.peerCount

5
> net.peerCount
1
> net.peerCount
1
>
```

**Console 2:**

```
myMac:console2 admin$ geth attach ipc:../node2/geth.ipc 
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.7.3-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.9.2
coinbase: 0x3fd97155061e47960b59b563a178fa248493017c
at block: 0 (Wed, 10 Jan 2018 21:36:58 +04)
 datadir: /Users/admin/EtherNet/testnet/node2
 modules: admin:1.0 clique:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> 
> admin.
admin.addPeer              admin.getNodeInfo          admin.nodeInfo             admin.sleepBlocks          admin.toLocaleString       
admin.constructor          admin.getPeers             admin.peers                admin.startRPC             admin.toString             
admin.datadir              admin.hasOwnProperty       admin.propertyIsEnumerable admin.startWS              admin.valueOf              
admin.exportChain          admin.importChain          admin.removePeer           admin.stopRPC              
admin.getDatadir           admin.isPrototypeOf        admin.sleep                admin.stopWS               
> admin.nodeInfo.
(anonymous): Line 2:1 Unexpected end of input
> admin.nodeInfo.enode
"enode://f48fcf69ba27442ff3813912ec12ea1ad249f14739dabfcadb3985c3654540e047700030adba5800bf33d0adbdd9ca5f1c47aae2498a0d9dafb8c2fd730969b4@[::]:3002"
> net.peerCount
1
> 
> net.peerCount
2
> net.peerCount
1
> net.peerCount
2
> 
> net.peerCount
3
> net.peerCount
5
>
```

I've ONLY 2 nodes and node2 is attached to node1. So, there is ONLY ONE PEER for each. But, why does the 'net.peerCount' keep changing, on subsequent execution of the same command?

Comment: Do you use the --noDiscover flag when launching your node? If note, other node try to connect (because of broadcast) but get rejected after that. To avoid that, launch geth with --nodiscover

Comment: You don't broadcast your information, but you receive connection attempts that get rejected because of a different genesis file. I had the same issue on my private chain. Just add the "--nodiscover" flag and check if this is really the problem.

Comment: @Andromelus, since this is a FRESH LOCAL setup and I've not turned on RPC as well, I'm not expecting anyone to know that my network-nodes exist. I didn't do anything to broadcast my network info. So, it's unlikely that other nodes would try to connect to my local network. Correct me if I'm wrong. And, below are the commands I used to launch the nodes:

    serv1$ geth --datadir node1 init bisminet.json
    serv1$ geth --datadir node1 --port 3000
    serv2$ geth --datadir node2 init bisminet.json
    serv2$ geth --datadir node2 --port 3002

Should I relaunch with --noDiscover flag?

Comment: @Andromelus, (Sorry, I deleted and re-added my comment with the 'markdown format'. But, failed again though! So, your answer appears above my comment. Just for the clarity of honoring your response).

Comment: Glad it worked, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node is receiving connection attempts from other nodes but get rejected because the genesis block/file is different.

Launch your node(s) with --nodiscover flag, this way they won't accept "random" connection from other nodes.

Comment: RELAUNCHED my nodes, as per your suggestion, and I'm getting 'net.peerCount' as 1, as expected!

Though, one correction in your comment:
--noDiscover flag 
must be in lower case: 
--nodiscover.

Thanks!